# How do I resolve IEnumerable of services of different types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, ienumerable

This is my interface:

```
public interface ISocialService<T> where T : ISocialModel
{
    public Task<List<T>> GetPosts();
}
```

I have 2 implementations of this interface.
This is how I try to register them

```
services.AddScoped<ISocialService<RedditPost>, RedditService>();
services.AddScoped<ISocialService<HackerNewsModel>, HackerNewsService>();
```

And finally this is how I try to resolve them.

```
public ScrapeJob(IEnumerable<ISocialService<ISocialModel>> socialServices)
{
    _socialServices = socialServices;
}
```

However socialServices is empty.
I think the problem lies in ISocialModel.
Anyone got suggestions how can I register or resolve them properly?

The reason why I want to use a generic interface is I want to inject specific service into a controller like this:

```
public HackerNewsController(ISocialService<HackerNewsModel> socialService)
        {
            _socialService = socialService;
        }
```

Comment: The problem is in the generic interface, create one more interface like ISocialService without generic parameter.

Comment: Tell more please what do you need to do in scrapeJob??

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I need to use a method from each service in socialServices.

Comment: What I try to do is to use GetPosts() method from each service in _socialServices. I try to do that in a foreach loop but _socialServices is just empty. My main question is why _socialServices is empty and if there is a way to get all implementations of ISocialService.

Comment: Why do you need generic then?

Comment: yes sure there is a way to get all implementation just get rid of generics

Comment: please provide full code so I can help to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have injected generic interface `IEnumerable<ISocialService<ISocialModel>>` but you don't have any classes that implement `ISocialService<ISocialModel>` instead you have `ISocialService<T>` implementation in classes.
so we need to update the code following way for example

```
public interface ISocialModel
{

}

public class RedditModel : ISocialModel
{

}

public interface ISocialService
{
     Task<List<ISocialModel>> GetPosts();
}

public interface ISocialService<T>: ISocialService where T : ISocialModel
{
     Task<List<T>> GetPosts();
}

public abstract class SocialServiceBase<T> : ISocialService<T> where T : ISocialModel

{
    async Task<List<ISocialModel>> ISocialService.GetPosts()
    {
        var posts = await GetPosts();

        return posts.Cast<ISocialModel>().ToList();
    }

   public abstract Task<List<T>> GetPosts();
    
}

public class RedditSocialService : SocialServiceBase<RedditModel>
{
    public override Task<List<RedditModel>> GetPosts()
    {
        //TODO: past your implementation here


    }
}
```

so in registration now you can write following code

```
    services.AddScoped<ISocialService, RedditService>(); 
    services.AddScoped<ISocialService, HackerNewsService>();
```

and later in class you can use like that

```
  class ScrapeJob
{
    private IEnumerable<ISocialService> _socialServices;

    public ScrapeJob(IEnumerable<ISocialService> socialServices)
    {
        _socialServices = socialServices;
    }


    public async Task DoScrapeJob()
    {
        foreach( var service in _socialServices)
        {
           var posts = await service.GetPosts();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to resolve specific service with this implementation? For example I want to resolve redditService in RedditController

Comment: Yes you can but you need to have a factory that will resolve you specific Service of specific type. Solution need to be modified!  That was my question! How do you want to use it? you just want to resolve all or you want to resolve specific it totally different things that can help to answer to your question

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this link:

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-registering-multiple-implementations-interface

You may need to register ISocialModel for both in order for it to be recognized as a collection of IEnumerable:
e.g.

```
services.AddScoped<ISocialModel, RedditService>();
services.AddScoped<ISocialModel, HackerNewsService>();
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think this is what I've done. The problem is when I try to resolve IEnumerable<ISocialService<ISocialModel>.
The ISocialService<(RedditPost or HackerNewsPost)> is working fine.